# Magento catalog_product_flat reindexing error with Shell and not getting corrected with truncating the table

Tags: shell, magento, phpmyadmin

I am trying to reindex my catalog_product_flat table in magento using Shell command. The reindexing is failing. with the following error.

I saw a solution on this site to 'truncate' the catalog_product_flat_# tables, and then reindex. Even then the reindex using shell has failed. Now all the 6 tables of catalog_product_flat_1-6 are empty. The site is still running, but God knows till when. PLS HELP

Product Flat Data index process unknown error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs' in /home/kya/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array) #5 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE`ca...', Array) #6 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(340): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...') #7 /home/kya/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(839): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE`ca...') #8 /home/kya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(799): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addColumn('catalog_product...', 'leg_angles', Array) #9 /home/kya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1) #10 /home/kya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll() #11 /home/kya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll() #12 /home/kya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll() #13 /home/kya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll() #14 /home/kya/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything() #15 /home/kya/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run() #16 {main

Comment: catalog_product_flat_* won't reindex - row size too large Answered here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229907/magento-reindex-problem/7232265#7232265 Non trivial answer converted to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this :
The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs'

Solution: You have too many attributes that are searchable.So magento during reindexing will populate all.
This is resulting in a very big row.

I suggest that you drop all flat tables as once columns are created they will not be removed.

Also make sure attribute data type needs lesser space.As row size is where there is an issue.

Comment: Thanks Satish! Sorry for late reply, but your answer helped me.

Comment: Would appreciate if you click this as answer